# Reload OS after motherboard change?

Tags: 14.04, hardware

I reloaded my PC with 14.04 64 bit and to be fair it was struggling. So I "upgraded" from a AMD 64bit 3500 to a Intel core duo. Pretty much just swapped out the motherboard and hooked everything up again. Out of interest I tried to boot to see if it would work, and it didn't flinch.

Is it worth reloading the PC with the new hardware when it appears to function perfectly?

Comment: As the old saying goes... if it ain't broke, don't fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it worth reloading the PC with the new hardware when it appears to function perfectly?

No, that is not needed. That is the fun of using generic drivers.

Only the graphics card can be an issue if you change from manufacturer (nVidia<>AMD) but that is easily solved: remove the display driver upfront if possible.